CSRF Token gets changed during the lifecycle of request in Laravel 11
I am trying to make a Payment Page in my Laravel 11 app and the logic is that ,the third party websites will redirect their user to my Payment Page and they will send api_token in the header of the request and other details in the request body.
Flow - Third Party Website redirects user to Payment Page and the user can login to my laravel app to see his vouchers and pay with the voucher if he has any available in his account.
The issue is i am getting 419 Page Expired and an exception thrown - CSRF token Mismatch ,when trying to login from the payment Page.
I created a testing route to mimick the third party website redirection.
I tried Logging in the CSRF token on different entry points for request. And i see that the CSRF token changes on showPaymentPage method.
Below is my Code
PaymentPageController
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\Voucher;
use App\Models\WhitelistedDomain;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class PaymentPageController extends Controller
{
    public function showPaymentPage(Request $request)
    {
        Log::info('showPaymentPage method invoked.');
        Log::info('CSRF Token (showPaymentPage): ' . $request->session()->token());

        $user = Auth::user();
        $vouchers = $user ? $user->vouchers()->where('voucher_status', 'active')->get() : [];

        $amount = $request->query('amount');
        $transactionCode = $request->query('transaction_code');
        $meta = $request->query('meta', []);

        $paymentDetails = [
            'amount' => $amount,
            'transaction_code' => $transactionCode,
            'meta' => $meta,
        ];

        $domain = $request->getHost();
        Log::info('showPaymentPage request: Transaction Code - ' . $transactionCode . ', Domain - ' . $domain . ', API Token - ' . $request->header('Authorization'));

        $apiToken = str_replace('Bearer ', '', $request->header('Authorization'));
        $validDomain = WhitelistedDomain::where('token', $apiToken)->where('domain', $domain)->exists();

        if (!$validDomain) {
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Invalid API token or domain mismatch.',
                'status' => 'error'
            ], 401);
        } else {
            return view('Api.paymentpage', compact('user', 'vouchers', 'paymentDetails'));
        }
    }

    public function processPayment(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'voucher_id' => 'required|exists:vouchers,id',
        ]);

        $voucherId = $request->input('voucher_id');
        $voucher = Voucher::findOrFail($voucherId);

        $voucher->voucher_status = 'redeemed';
        $voucher->voucher_redeemed_at = now();
        $voucher->save();

        return redirect()->to('https://thirdpartywebsite.com/payment-success');
    }

    public function newlogin(Request $request)
    {
        Log::info('CSRF Token (before login): ' . $request->session()->token());

        $credentials = $request->only('username', 'password');

        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            $request->session()->regenerate();
            Log::info('CSRF Token (after login): ' . $request->session()->token());

            return redirect()->route('payment.show');
        }

        return back()->withErrors([
            'username' => 'The provided credentials do not match our records.',
        ]);
    }

}


Below is my Blade View file for the controller
<!-- resources/views/payment.blade.php -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>
    @vite('resources/css/app.css')
    @if (env('APP_ENV') !== 'local')
        <script src="{{ secure_asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
    @else
        <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
    @endif
    <!-- Include Alpine.js -->
    <script src="//unpkg.com/alpinejs" defer></script>
</head>
<body class="font-sans antialiased bg-gray-100">
<div class="min-h-screen flex flex-col">
    <header class="bg-gray-200 shadow-md rounded-b-lg px-8 py-2 flex items-center justify-center">
        <img src="{{ asset('KingVoucherLogo.png') }}" alt="Logo" class="h-1/2 w-1/2 object-cover">
    </header>
    @if ($errors->any())
        <div class="bg-red-100 rounded-lg px-4 py-3 mb-4 text-red-700">
            <ul>
                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
    @endif
    <!-- Payment Details Section -->
    <div x-data="{ open: true }" class="mb-1 mt-2">
        <div @click="open = !open" class="bg-blue-500 text-white p-4 rounded-t-lg cursor-pointer">
            <h2 class="text-lg font-semibold">Payment Details</h2>
        </div>
        <div x-show="open" class="bg-white shadow-md rounded-b-lg p-4">
            <p><strong>Transaction ID:</strong> {{ $paymentDetails['transaction_code'] }}</p>
            <p><strong>Amount:</strong> {{ $paymentDetails['amount'] }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    @if (Auth::check())
        <main class="flex-grow px-4 py-6">
            @if ($errors->any())
                <div class="bg-red-100 rounded-lg px-4 py-3 mb-4 text-red-700">
                    <ul>
                        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                        @endforeach
                    </ul>
                </div>
            @endif
            @if (isset($user) && !empty($user))
                <div class="text-sm">
                    <h4 class="text-center mb-2">Welcome, {{ $user->name }}</h4>
                </div>
            @endif

            <h4 class="text-center mb-3">Select & Pay With Voucher Below</h4>
            <form action="{{ route('payment.process') }}" method="post" class="shadow-md rounded-lg p-4" x-data="{ selectedVoucher: null }">
                @csrf
                <div class="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-3 gap-6">
                    @foreach ($vouchers as $voucher)
                        <div @click="selectedVoucher = (selectedVoucher === {{ $voucher->id }}) ? null : {{ $voucher->id }}" :class="{ 'border-blue-500 border-4': selectedVoucher === {{ $voucher->id }} }" class="relative rounded-lg shadow-lg overflow-hidden cursor-pointer">
                            <input type="radio" name="voucher_id" value="{{ $voucher->id }}" class="absolute opacity-0" x-model="selectedVoucher">
                            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/swnZ5b1/Front-Side-Card.jpg" alt="Credit Card Background" class="w-full h-auto object-cover">
                            <div class="absolute inset-0 flex flex-col justify-between text-white p-4">
                                <div class="mb-2">
                                    <h2 class="text-base md:text-lg lg:text-xl font-semibold">Voucher Code</h2>
                                    <p class="text-xs md:text-sm lg:text-base">{{ $voucher->voucher_code }}</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="mb-2 flex justify-between">
                                    <div>
                                        <h2 class="text-base md:text-lg lg:text-xl font-semibold">Amount</h2>
                                        <p class="text-xs md:text-sm lg:text-base">{{ $voucher->voucher_amount }}</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <h2 class="text-base md:text-lg lg:text-xl font-semibold">Status</h2>
                                        <p class="text-xs md:text-sm lg:text-base">
                                            @php
                                                $statusMap = [
                                                    'active' => 'Active',
                                                    'expired' => 'Expired',
                                                    'redeemed' => 'Redeemed',
                                                    'cashedout' => 'CashedOut',
                                                ];

                                                $formattedStatus = $statusMap[$voucher->voucher_status] ?? $voucher->voucher_status;
                                            @endphp
                                            {{ $formattedStatus }}
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="flex justify-between mb-2">
                                    <div>
                                        <h2 class="text-base md:text-xs lg:text-xl font-light">Issue</h2>
                                        <p class="text-xs md:text-xs lg:text-base">{{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($voucher->voucher_issue_time)->format('Y-m-d') }}</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <h2 class="text-base md:text-xs lg:text-xl font-light">Expiry</h2>
                                        <p class="text-xs md:text-xs lg:text-base">
                                            @php
                                                $expiryDate = Carbon\Carbon::parse($voucher->voucher_expiration_date)->toDateString();
                                                $currentDate = Carbon\Carbon::now()->toDateString();
                                                $expiryText = ($currentDate >= $expiryDate) ? 'Expired' : $expiryDate;
                                            @endphp
                                            {{ $expiryText }}
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="flex items-center justify-center">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox h-5 w-5 text-blue-600" x-show="selectedVoucher === {{ $voucher->id }}" checked>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    @endforeach
                </div>
                <div class="flex">
                    <button type="submit" class="flex-auto items-center mt-6 py-2 px-4 rounded-md focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2"
                            :class="selectedVoucher ? 'bg-indigo-500 text-white hover:bg-indigo-600' : 'bg-gray-400 text-gray-200 cursor-not-allowed'"
                            :disabled="!selectedVoucher">
                        Process Payment
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </main>
    @else
        <main class="flex-grow px-4 py-6 bg-gray-300">
            <div class="bg-gray-200 shadow-md rounded p-6">
                <form action="{{ route('payment.login') }}" method="POST" class="space-y-4">
                    @csrf
                    <h6 class="text-center">Login to Pay</h6>
                    <div>
                        <label for="username" class="block text-gray-700">Username:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" required class="block w-full mt-1 p-2 border rounded">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="password" class="block text-gray-700">Password:</label>
                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" required class="block w-full mt-1 p-2 border rounded">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="w-full py-2 px-4 bg-blue-500 text-white rounded shadow-md hover:bg-blue-600">
                        Login
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </main>
    @endif
</div>
</body>
</html>


Below is my Routes file
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/welcome', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
Route::middleware(['web'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/payment', [\App\Http\Controllers\Api\PaymentPageController::class, 'showPaymentPage'])->name('payment.show')->middleware(\App\Http\Middleware\LogRequestMiddleware::class);
    Route::post('/payment', [\App\Http\Controllers\Api\PaymentPageController::class, 'processPayment'])->name('payment.process');
    Route::post('/newlogin', [\App\Http\Controllers\Api\PaymentPageController::class, 'newlogin'])->name('payment.login');
    Route::get('/test-payment-page', function () {
        // Log the CSRF token before the request
        Log::info('CSRF Token (before request): ' . session()->token());

        // URL of your payment page
        $paymentPageUrl = url('/payment');

        // API token and details
        $apiToken = '1|yYckeGo8xEtwVQw3QzBaE7qmTc2C5uLC1YZqJJgVff1bac5d';
        $details = [
            'amount' => 100,
            'transaction_code' => 'TRX123456789',
            'meta' => [
                'customer_id' => 'CUST123',
                'order_id' => 'ORDER456'
            ],
        ];

        // Make a request to the payment page with the Bearer token and details
        $response = Http::withHeaders([
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $apiToken,
        ])->get($paymentPageUrl, $details);

        // Log the CSRF token after the request
        Log::info('CSRF Token (after request): ' . session()->token());

        // Return the response content
        return $response->body();
    });
});


Below is my Middleware - LogRequestMiddleware
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use App\Models\ApiUserRequestLog;
use App\Models\User;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Laravel\Sanctum\PersonalAccessToken;
use Laravel\Telescope\Telescope;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class LogRequestMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     * This will log all the requests made by the Apiuser in our system,
     * so we can show them the Realtime table in their reports section
     *
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response)  $next
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
    {

        // Retrieve user ID from bearer token
        $userId = $this->getUserIdFromToken($request);

        // Proceed with the request if user is identified
        if ($userId) {

            // Log the request
            $log = new ApiUserRequestLog();
            $log->user_id = $userId;
            $log->transaction_id = $request->input('transaction_code');
            $log->amount = $request->input('amount');
            $log->meta = $request->input('meta');
            $log->request_data = json_encode($request->all());
            $log->request_method = $request->method();
            $log->request_full_url = $request->fullUrl();
            //$log->request_uri = $request->uri();
            $log->client_ip = $request->ip();
            $log->user_agent = $request->userAgent();
            //$log->response_data = $response->getContent();
            $response = $next($request);

            // Capture the response status code
            $statusCode = $response->getStatusCode();

            // Update the log model with the status code (optional, can use Telescope tags)
            $log->response_data = $statusCode;

            $log->save();
        }

        return $response;

    }

    private function getUserIdFromToken(Request $request): ?int
    {
        // Extract bearer token from Authorization header
        $token = $request->bearerToken();

        if (!$token) {
            return null;
        }

        // Get the Personal Access Token model
        $personalAccessToken = PersonalAccessToken::findToken($token);

        if (!$personalAccessToken) {
            return null;
        }

        // Retrieve the associated User model and return user ID
        return $personalAccessToken->tokenable->id;
    }
}


Below is the Log Viewer to show logs

Below is my config/session.php
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Str;

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Session Driver
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option determines the default session driver that is utilized for
    | incoming requests. Laravel supports a variety of storage options to
    | persist session data. Database storage is a great default choice.
    |
    | Supported: "file", "cookie", "database", "apc",
    |            "memcached", "redis", "dynamodb", "array"
    |
    */

    'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'database'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Lifetime
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
    | to be allowed to remain idle before it expires. If you want them
    | to expire immediately when the browser is closed then you may
    | indicate that via the expire_on_close configuration option.
    |
    */

    'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 120),

    'expire_on_close' => env('SESSION_EXPIRE_ON_CLOSE', false),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Encryption
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option allows you to easily specify that all of your session data
    | should be encrypted before it's stored. All encryption is performed
    | automatically by Laravel and you may use the session like normal.
    |
    */

    'encrypt' => env('SESSION_ENCRYPT', false),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session File Location
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When utilizing the "file" session driver, the session files are placed
    | on disk. The default storage location is defined here; however, you
    | are free to provide another location where they should be stored.
    |
    */

    'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Database Connection
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "database" or "redis" session drivers, you may specify a
    | connection that should be used to manage these sessions. This should
    | correspond to a connection in your database configuration options.
    |
    */

    'connection' => env('SESSION_CONNECTION'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Database Table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "database" session driver, you may specify the table to
    | be used to store sessions. Of course, a sensible default is defined
    | for you; however, you're welcome to change this to another table.
    |
    */

    'table' => env('SESSION_TABLE', 'sessions'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cache Store
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using one of the framework's cache driven session backends, you may
    | define the cache store which should be used to store the session data
    | between requests. This must match one of your defined cache stores.
    |
    | Affects: "apc", "dynamodb", "memcached", "redis"
    |
    */

    'store' => env('SESSION_STORE'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Sweeping Lottery
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Some session drivers must manually sweep their storage location to get
    | rid of old sessions from storage. Here are the chances that it will
    | happen on a given request. By default, the odds are 2 out of 100.
    |
    */

    'lottery' => [2, 100],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may change the name of the session cookie that is created by
    | the framework. Typically, you should not need to change this value
    | since doing so does not grant a meaningful security improvement.
    |
    */

    'cookie' => env(
        'SESSION_COOKIE',
        Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_session'
    ),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The session cookie path determines the path for which the cookie will
    | be regarded as available. Typically, this will be the root path of
    | your application, but you're free to change this when necessary.
    |
    */

    'path' => env('SESSION_PATH', '/'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Domain
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This value determines the domain and subdomains the session cookie is
    | available to. By default, the cookie will be available to the root
    | domain and all subdomains. Typically, this shouldn't be changed.
    |
    */

    'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | HTTPS Only Cookies
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | By setting this option to true, session cookies will only be sent back
    | to the server if the browser has a HTTPS connection. This will keep
    | the cookie from being sent to you when it can't be done securely.
    |
    */

    'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | HTTP Access Only
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Setting this value to true will prevent JavaScript from accessing the
    | value of the cookie and the cookie will only be accessible through
    | the HTTP protocol. It's unlikely you should disable this option.
    |
    */

    'http_only' => env('SESSION_HTTP_ONLY', true),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Same-Site Cookies
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option determines how your cookies behave when cross-site requests
    | take place, and can be used to mitigate CSRF attacks. By default, we
    | will set this value to "lax" to permit secure cross-site requests.
    |
    | See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#samesitesamesite-value
    |
    | Supported: "lax", "strict", "none", null
    |
    */

    'same_site' => env('SESSION_SAME_SITE', 'lax'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Partitioned Cookies
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Setting this value to true will tie the cookie to the top-level site for
    | a cross-site context. Partitioned cookies are accepted by the browser
    | when flagged "secure" and the Same-Site attribute is set to "none".
    |
    */

    'partitioned' => env('SESSION_PARTITIONED_COOKIE', false),

];


I tried logging the CSRF token but i am unable to figure out why it is getting changed.
What could  be possibly Wrong with request, why the CSRF token is getting changed. Please help me solve it.
